# Laravel complains for missing non-nullable value, but it is there

Tags: json, laravel, angular, laravel-5

I have the following code in Laravel 5.4.* to store an array of JSON objects.

```
Sample::where('contest_id', $request->get('contest_id'))
                ->where('type', '0')
                ->delete();
if ( $request->get('extra3') ) {
   $samples = $request->get('samples');
   //return $samples;
   Sample::insert($samples);
}
```

I had an error for a missing value that is not nullable, so I started the debugging.

This is the return of the $samples, just before the encoding:

```
[
  {
    "id": 16,
    "contest_id": "35",
    "product_id": "2",
    "supplier_id": "2",
    "quantity": "5",
    "type": "0",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
  },
  {
    "contest_id": 35,
    "type": "0",
    "product_id": "4",
    "supplier_id": "3",
    "quantity": 3
  }
]
```

However, if I commented out the return and let the eloquent runs, the insert is messed up.

This is the full error

`{"error":{"message":"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: samples.supplier_id (SQL: insert into \"samples\" (\"contest_id\", \"created_at\", \"id\", \"product_id\", \"quantity\", \"supplier_id\", \"type\", \"updated_at\") select 1 as \"contest_id\",  as \"created_at\", 5 as \"id\", 2 as \"product_id\", 5 as \"quantity\", 2 as \"supplier_id\", 0 as \"type\",  as \"updated_at\" union all select 1 as \"contest_id\", 1 as \"created_at\", 1 as \"id\", 1 as \"product_id\", 0 as \"quantity\", ? as \"supplier_id\", ? as \"type\", ? as \"updated_at\")","code":"23000","status_code":500}}`

Edit: A few more details how I reproduce the error. I don't have it on every insert request, but only after a certain process.

I have a dynamic form with Angular where user can create as many models of `Sample` as she wants. The first time the user send the request with the models, Laravel saves those without an error.

When I refresh the page and the form is created automatically with the data that I had in the DB, if I remove one of them and create a new one, but keep at least one of the previous data, then I have the error.

Just before the above code, I have a line that delete data from the same table, so everything that was there, isn't during the `insert` command.

HTML of the dynamic form:

```
<div class="row col-md-12" *ngFor="let input of initSamples; let i=index">
     <div class="col-md-4">
          <label *ngIf="i==0" for="product{{i}}" class="col-md-12">Product</label>
          <div class="input-group">
               <select name="product{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="input.product_id" id="product{{i}}" class="form-control">
                     <option *ngFor="let product of products" value="{{product.id}}">{{product.name}}</option>
               </select>
          </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
          <label *ngIf="i==0" for="supplier{{i}}" class="col-md-12">Supplier</label>
          <div class="input-group">
               <select name="supplier{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="input.supplier_id" id="supplier{{i}}" class="form-control ">
                     <option *ngFor="let supplier of suppliers" value="{{supplier.id}}">{{supplier.name}}</option>
               </select>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
         <label *ngIf="i==0" for="quantity{{i}}" class="col-md-12">Quantity</label>
         <input type="number" min=1 step=1 [(ngModel)]="input.quantity" id="quantity{{i}}" name="quantity{{i}}" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you trying to insert json or non json data?
Also what does $samples contain?

Comment: @SagarGulati The JSON array on the question is the output of the $samples.

Comment: so you want to insert json encoded data in database why are you even decoding it?
You can simply use    Sample::insert($samples);

Comment: I was initially upload them as Form-Data and the $samples was just a string. Now, I tried it with a json/application too without the encoding and I have the same error.

Comment: What you could try it as
first store $samples as an variable $sample = $samples
then convert them, $newsample = json_decode($sample, true)
then try to insert it?
<br/>
Still not sure what exact error and where you are getting it.

Comment: @SagarGulati The error is the http response from my request. The insert fails and I have the NOT NULL contraint error.

Comment: Not sure to help out without seeing the live errors coming up and the manipulation of data it seems